# DBCC CHECKDB Error 2706

Tags: sql-server-2016, dbcc-checkdb

A CHECKDB job has recently started returning error number 2706 for 2 databases (msdb and a user database).
The msdb.dbo.suspect_pages table is empty though. When I run CHECKDB manually it says:
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database 'msdb'.

I'm not sure if it's related, but just before the error started appearing we upgraded SQL Server 2016 from  CU17 to SP3.

Where can I find information on what error number 2706 means?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get more information here: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/sql2017-cu21-checkdb-with-extended_logical_checks where user Albert Hamidullin reports:

> I caught the error, it appears twice with this message "Table 'fn_available_backups' does not exist."
>
> Two objects - two messages
>
> It turns out that dbcc does not always correctly understand whether an object is a table or not.
>
> I caught the same errors on other databases, where table types were the culprit

There are two table-valued functions in *msdb* named *fn_available_backups*, one in the *managed_backup* schema, and one in the *smart_admin* schema.

The error is thrown when `EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS` attempts to check for corruption in statistics associated with indexes on the return table variables.

Comment: Thank you for the information!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug and has been fixed in 2017 CU30 and 2019 CU17.

Error 2706 occurs when you run `DBCC CHECKDB WITH EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS` against a database by using the Table-Valued Function (TVF) that uses indexes. Here is the error message:

> Table '%.*ls' does not exist.

As this is 2016 I don't think there will be any fix for it as only security updates will be issued.

Comment: Thanks for the update